# var mqtt = require('mqtt'); resulting in error

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I have installed 'node.js' and then executed '**npm install mqtt**' from 'node.js' command line to install 'mqtt.js'. Now to test 'mqtt client' I am trying to execute :
        **var mqtt = require('mqtt');**
which results in error saying:

```
  "Error: Cannot find module 'mqtt'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at repl:1:12
   at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
   at repl.js:249:20
   at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
   at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
   at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)"
```

Comment: Is there an `mqtt` folder in your `node_modules` folder that lies on the same path than your executing `*.js` file?

Comment: There is no folder by name mqtt in my node_modules folder. It only has one folder npm.

Comment: @Amberlamps : This the directory structure - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm . Inside this I have one folder by name node_modules. I had installed/downloaded express and mqtt using npm install command. It has placed the folder in the directory C:\Users\I055406\node_modules. Do you see any mismatch here. Bear with me as I am a novice in this topic. Shall I place the mqtt and express inside the node_modules folder which has npm inside it?

Comment: Try placing you express and mqtt project in C:/Users/I055406/your_project/

Comment: The issue I was facing got resolved....
now var mqtt = require('mqtt'); executes without issues.
However I have noticed that I cannot create client by saying
var client = new mqtt.MQTTClient(1883, '127.0.0.1', 'ClientID');
it results in error saying
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at repl:1:14
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at repl.js:249:20
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
  
but var client = mqtt.createClient() executes without issues.
Could you please help.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to add the MQTT library.
If you have npm package manager installed on the server, you should run `npm install mqtt --save`

For detailed information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt

Answer (score 2):

For requiring Node.js module, refer to this tutorial which is pretty detailed.
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm

By the way, `createClient()` has been deprecated by mqtt module, use `connect()` instead.

If you ever want to test your MQTT client with a ready online broker, try http://www.robomq.io.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue that Node developers face. While working on Unix systems, sometimes it may not allow you to install such packages. For that, you will need `sudo` permissions. Sometimes, the package is installed but only in your local modules, and when you try to import it from outside of the directory, the error occurs. Sometimes, your compiler read your dependencies, but not able to find this package in that, at that time also you face this error. 
Anyways, don't worry. You just have to follow some steps below.

1. A best practice is to `initialize` your project using `npm init` before starting development. This will initialize your project and generate `package.json` file.
2. Then, if you want any library as dependencies, try `--save` with `npm install` command. This will save your dependency in `package.json` file. 
   e.g. `npm install mqtt --save`
3. If any package is not found after installing, install it globally by `-g` flag. 
   Globally installed packages will be accessible within your system. e.g. `npm install mqtt -g`.

Note: Unix system needs `SUDO` permission for installing it globally.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the command line for node.js, it searches for node modules that are installed globally which is usually in the directory /usr/lib/node_modules in Linux machines. 
When you run npm install, the node modules are installed locally in the same directory where the node terminal was launched.
If you want to access node modules in the node terminal, you need to run npm install mqtt -g where -g stands for global installation. 
Usually Linux machines don't allow normal users to access /usr/lib/node_modules so it'll be better to run it as `sudo npm install mqtt -g`

Comment: sudo: npm: command not found, gives this error